# How to create a table in 18c express edition

Tags: oracle

I just finished installing oracle 18c express edition on windows 8 laptop. During the installations, I did not enter any user name. I entered my password though.

At the end of the installation, I get this screen:

[image]

I connected Oracle database using sql plus as follows:

```
SQL> / as sysdba
```

I also entered the following commands in sql plus and all have worked. I was just following youtube tutorial without understanding everything.

```
SQL>alter pluggable database all open;
SQL>alter pluggable database all save state ;
SQL>select name from v$pdbs;
SQL> connect sys/oracle@localhost:1521/XEPDB1 as sysdba;
SQL> alter user hr identified by hr;
SQL> alter user hr account unlock;
SQL>connect hr/hr@localhost:1521/XEPDB1;
SQL> select * from employees;
SQL> CREATE TABLE TEST1 (CUSID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL);
```

This is the first time I am doing it. I tried to connect to a database using SYS as the user name and the password but did not connect.

```
SQL> Enter user name: SYS;
Enter password: Welcome1
```

SYS - During the installation, it said sys, system, and pdbadmin accounts. So I assume sys could be one of the user names.

Password - I entered the same password I used at the time of installation. I can connect to the database using `/ as sysdba`. But I am not sure what this code meaning and what the user name and password and what database it is trying to connect. What would be the database name, user name and password?

---

Update 1

I created a connection in sql developer. Below shows the connection properties.
I created a table(sqldev2) in sql developer, inserted rows, and selected the data just fine.

[image]

Next, I went to sql plus and tried to select the same data from sqldev2 table but it shows no rows selected. I am assuming sql plus and sql developer may be pointing to two different databases?

[image]

How can I tell which database I am connected using the sql developer?
How can I connect to the same database using the sql plus?
This way I can work on the same database using the sql plus and sql developer.

---

Update 2

In Eclipse IDE, I had this code to connect to database. After that, I created a table (testtble) in Eclipse.

```
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
   System.out.println("Driver Loaded");
   Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe", "sys as sysdba","pw");
```

In SQL Plus, I connected to the db using "/ as sysdba". After that, I also tried to select * from testtble but it shows no table. I am assuming sql plus might be pointing to something different than what I used in eclipse. How should I connect to the database from SQL plus so I could see the table "testtble" in sql plus?

Comment: you should connect always with sys without password using / as sysdba. Changing the password of sys requires a special method in order to do it correctly. you need to check whether you want to change that password or not.

Comment: when you connect with sys, you connect to the root container, then you can switch to any of the pluggable databases you have created by using ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = xxxx

Comment: Above I created a table. What database did I create the table? Just curious. If I like to connect to the database using SYS user name, what would be the sql plus commands to connect to the database?

Answer (score 0):

To check in which pluggable database you are currently connected in SQL*Plus use:

```
show con_name
```

If you connect to Oracle using a connect string *that is using a database service mapped to a pluggable database (PDB)*, you will be connected directly to the related PDB.

Try different connections strings and check with `show con_name`.

Comment: When connecting with SQL Developer do *not* use SID but use the service name that is mapped to the right PDB: `XEPDB1` should be mapped to  `PDB1`. Do the same with SQL*Plus using `@XEPDB1` in connect string.

Comment: I guess that part I am lost how to point to the same database via sql plus. Please see the update 2. Can you please share some sql plus commands to type in per update 1 or 2?